# Print one word per line

Tags: unix, awk, sed, ksh

I tried almost everything, sed, awk, `tr`, but...

I'm trying to output a file containing this

```
 2079 May 19 13:37 temp.sh
 1024 May 23 17:09 mirrad
 478 May 26 14:48 unzip.sh
```

like this

```
 2079
 May
 19
 13:37
 .
 .
 .
```

So each string will be printed out one at the time in a variable.

Comment: Post what you have tried so far ?

Comment: What does `in a variable` mean at the end of your question?

Comment: special thanks to all of you for all these answers. all answers I received were corrected and easy to implement. again thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another simple one liner using `xargs`

```
xargs -n 1 <file
```

where `-n` explanation from `man` page:-

```
-n max-args, --max-args=max-args
       Use at most max-args arguments per command line.  Fewer than
       max-args arguments will be used if the size (see the -s
       option) is exceeded, unless the -x option is given, in which
       case xargs will exit.
```

will produce output as

```
#!/bin/bash
$ xargs -n1 <tmp.txt
2079
May
19
13:37
temp.sh
1024
May
23
17:09
mirrad
```

with `-n` value as 2 it gives

```
#!/bin/bash     
$ xargs -n2 <tmp.txt
2079 May
19 13:37
temp.sh 1024
May 23
17:09 mirrad
```

**Note**

The suggestion with `xargs` only works for a simple input as shown in OP. As such the solution doesn't work for huge files (needing high in memory processing) or in files containing lines with quotes. See other answers involving `awk` for the same.

Comment: nothing to say other than thank you clean and efficient

Comment: This is very slow for large files, (m)awk solution below is much faster.

Comment: This fails if the file contains unmatched single quotes.

Comment: @Kyle: I've made a disclaimer at the end now. OP's input did not mention about explicit huge files or ones containing quotes. Perhaps you can revert the downvote now

Answer (score 5):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -v OFS='\n' '{$1=$1}1' file
```

Comment: nothing to say other than thank you clean and efficient

Comment: appears to match 'xargs -n 1' output but without the slowness and issue with single quotes.

Answer (score 4):

with **awk**

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=" "} 1' file
```

**output**

```
2079
May
19
13:37
temp.sh
1024
May
23
17:09
mirrad
478
May
26
14:48
unzip.sh
```

Comment: special thanks to all of you for all these answers. all answers I received were corrected and easy to implement.                                                                     again thank you

Comment: this may leave unwanted whitespace in the output.

Answer (score 2):

Get the arguments for `printf` from the file:

```
printf "%s\n" $(<file)
```

Comment: nothing to say other than thank you clean and efficient

Answer (score 2):

Just one `cat` and `tr` can do this easily

```
cat input.txt|tr ' ' "\n"
```

or

EDIT:

the better one, without UUOC

```
tr ' ' "\n" < input.txt
```

Comment: and you don't even need or want the cat: `tr ' ' '\n' < input.txt`. Google UUOC.

Comment: @EdMorton - Thanks for info. Yes **concatenating(`cat`) it with nothing at all is a waste of time**. Just pasted excerpts from google :)

Comment: nothing to say other than thank you clean and efficient

Comment: If you think this answer has solved or answered your question properly. Please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? for more information

Answer (score 1):

I'll go ahead and answer this since I flagged it with the wrong duplicate question.

Use `tr`:

```
echo "Mary had a little lamb" | tr ' ' '\n'
```

In the command above you are replacing `' '` with a newline, `'\n'`.

Use `sed`:

```
echo "Mary had a little lamb" | sed 's/ /\n/g'
```

If you have multiple spaces you want to turn into a single newline, use `s/  */\n/g` instead.  That is `/` followed by *two* spaces then an `*`.

Comment: nothing to say other than thank you clean and efficient